# How to pass parameter on onClick in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to **pass few values on clicking** a button in **ReactJS Functional Component**, below is the code snippet.

```
<span className="edit" onClick={ onClickEdit(value.title, value.details)}> 
   <img src={editImg} height="15" width="15" />
</span>
```

This is showing an error. As I know we can't use 'this' keyword in Functional Component. Please help with this.

Comment: `onClick={() => onClickEdit(value.title, value.details)}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

const App = () => {
return (
<div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
    {/* <SearchBar /> */}
    <button onClick={()=>testFunc('gi','jgj')}>click me</button>
</div>

)}

const testFunc = (a, b) => {
console.log(a, b);
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function like below snippet

```
<Button variant="info" onClick={() => editUser(userObject)}>Edit</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` props expects a function. By doing what you are doing, you are not passing a function, but calling a function directly in the prop.

You can pass an anonymous function (a function that is not declared) directly in the prop:

```
<span className="edit" onClick={() => onClickEdit(value.title, value.details)}> 
   <img src={editImg} height="15" width="15" />
</span>
```